# Trouble Classifying Music with Scikitlearn and kNearestNeighbor Classifier

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on classifying 30 second samples of music into one of four genres: ["electronic", "hip hop", "jazz", "rock"] and I would appreciate any kind of help.

I have generated my own data set from mp3 files. Within my "dataset" directory, I have arranged 100 songs by genre, putting 25 in subdirectories for each genre (i.e. I have "electronic", "hip hop", etc subdirectories).

So far, I have extracted 30 second samples of each of these mp3 files, normalized the signal so that no sample exceeds -32 or -18 dB, mixed them down to mono, and converted them to wav (with pyDub).

Next I used librosa to extract mfccs (mel frequency cepstral coefficients) for the 1292 frames in each song. Then I scaled the data so it has zero mean and unit variance using sklearn's preprocessing module.

I took these values and saved them to a csv file of MFFCs, where each row is a frame and each column is one of 12 coefficients.

So you can get an idea, the song followed by the first 20 frames:
Julio Bashmore - Au Seve.mp3

```
1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
-1.6792870551627723,-0.3842983399875271,-0.4027844785642914,0.7165034707424635,-0.6823681099880697,0.8160136728323858,-1.5263184054951733,1.1145290823984928,-0.21784328023531235,0.047527570975473235,0.32866412875434237,1.869661743729989
2.4841536110972022,-0.5831476248573247,0.37058328670683277,-1.4599220579565508,-0.35449671920732007,-1.1326787825224918,0.5880762356956317,-0.8108172607843107,0.010134004741811507,-0.14931018884055094,0.8707111843072819,0.1667143116197902
2.0939135826765907,-0.4778720879089441,0.26530387765936375,-1.7076132053582773,0.11305806361775678,-1.310823349961563,1.1669240812438573,-0.8627333493359391,-0.19252158214293175,-0.039523355794829566,0.6658161856594883,0.2860711396454278
1.0127547898943148,-0.6547501371081066,-0.202002065081406,-1.7889468252345162,1.1632837017143651,-0.9288351063974712,2.070078331574107,-0.7601750354687623,-0.27909671541985936,-0.13713166210030908,0.2267359005199065,0.27808482310773774
0.06572087004052392,-1.8740496505118946,-0.9604185325425617,-1.0163364869696865,1.5840872642483552,-0.16659361108422382,1.7806813371087853,0.055159751832777354,0.6842054675590546,0.42350598071605017,-0.3324771084186967,-0.24348528197848257
0.7159690101152768,-2.6235135217332606,-0.9099658866643047,-0.19653348650619468,1.0348534863167884,-0.6771927176675163,1.0703663687805878,0.3981886714210787,0.8503521825769755,0.4055860454830591,-0.11841556456925736,0.05030541244676532
0.8810398765824345,-2.7727001749452045,-0.8484274387283207,0.14839104995756489,0.9124992899968386,-0.5987705973726993,0.6471053665081234,0.43190059553550836,0.9028748015921237,0.3425604687141461,-0.20209176692016032,0.15561852907964296
1.5217565976091,-2.5946551685896044,-0.3924558895014341,0.36743931340001096,0.9126773048246598,-0.7581004315396501,0.4463892360730688,0.42969123923287,0.7276796949470707,-0.0079165602005986,-0.580154306587985,-0.07235102966750707
2.08861621898524,-1.2804976691396324,0.46640912894919145,0.14007051920782673,0.9100754665932002,-1.51168507329552,0.7161640071116147,0.34780954351977644,0.30123647629161765,-1.103443008391695,-0.7900432022174468,-0.2847124076141728
1.300078728794466,-0.6136862665584394,0.5321920666343034,-0.25881789165042973,1.2648582642185016,-1.7504670292559645,1.4050993480861744,0.354988549965
```

I tried simply compiling the 1292 frame vectors for each song into one big vector for each genre, and use that as input for scikitlearn's kNN algorithm. I am getting very unfortunate results, I just get a vector filled with "rock"

I'm fairly certain I'm not really going about it correctly at all, but
I have the following two functions. The first one creates this feature vector for each genre. The second one simply trains it using each genre vector and a vector filled with labels for the genre.

```
def create_np_vector(db_read, start_row):
    num_frames = 1292
    num_songs = 25
    num_coefs = 12
    #vector for all features of every song/sample of that genre
    genre_vec = np.empty([(num_frames * num_songs), num_coefs])
    db_reader = csv.reader(db_read)
    for row in itertools.islice(db_reader, start_row, start_row + 25):
        id = row[0]
        path = row[2]
        mfcc_file = path + "/csv/" + id + ".csv"
        mfcc_reader = csv.reader(open(mfcc_file, 'r'))
        frame_num = 0
        for mfcc_row in mfcc_reader:
            frame_vec = np.array(mfcc_row)
            genre_vec[frame_num] = frame_vec
            frame_num = frame_num + 1
    return genre_vec

def train_knn(db_read, knn):
    genres = ["electronic", "hip hop", "jazz", "rock"]
    line_num = [0, 26, 51, 76]
    x = 0
    for genre in genres:
        vec = create_np_vector(db_read, line_num[x])
        x = x + 1
        print(genre)
        knn.fit(vec, [genre for x in range(25*1292)])
```

What exactly should I be doing here? I've been trying to use this as a resource: http://modelai.gettysburg.edu/2012/music/, but I'm still quite lost. Should I be calculating a mean vector and covariance matrix for each audio file?

Even if I did that, what would I do with the two vectors for each file?

Comment: Note that it's possible that your machine learning code is perfectly fine and that MFCCs are just not very good for genre categorization. MFCCs are probably going to be better at capturing characteristics like key, spectral balance, over mix, etc. Genre is much more determined by rhythm, chords, and instrumentation, none of which are really captured by MFCCs.

Comment: MFCCs have been used for genre class for a long time though...

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I just don't see how they can capture information relevant to genre

Answer (score 0):

MFCC is a good approach for starter. However, it's very likely that having 12 coefficients is going to overwhelm your classifier. Take mean and your performance for sure will improve. [Here](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch09/02_ceps_based_classifier.py) is a complete solution as described in [Building Machine Learning Systems with Python](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/building-machine-learning/9781784392772/) by by Luis Pedro Coelho and Willi Richert.

You can get a free trial from the web site. Enough to read the chapter on exactly this: music genre classification.

Answer (score 0):

With only 25 samples per class and 1292 features per sample it will be extremely hard to discover any pattern it in, the data is too noisy. Too reduce the complexity you can try to compute summary statistics of the MFCC data, like mean/std/min/max/skew/kurtosis for each band. To capture some temporal variations you may want to also include summaries of MFCC frame deltas.

MFCC features were originally designed for speech. You may want to try using some features that are more tailored for music. [libessentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/) and [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html) both have feature extractors for things like rhythm, musical key etc.